# Query in Laravel 5.7 and PostgreSQL

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem to make a query in Laravel

My query in POSTGRESQL is:

```
SELECT con.id, con.vehiculo_id, con.cre, ve.chofer_id, ve.placa
FROM conciliaciones as con 
JOIN vehiculos as ve
on con.vehiculo_id = ve.id or con.vehiculo_id IS NULL or con.vehiculo_id IS NOT NULL;
```

The problem with the query is that the plate is repeated when there should only be 1 single row with the data plate the rest is null

I have the following code, but it does not work:

```
$conciliacion = DB::table('conciliaciones')
    ->join('vehiculos','conciliaciones.vehiculo_id','=','vehiculos.id')
    ->select('conciliaciones.*','vehiculos.placa')           
    ->whereNull('conciliaciones.vehiculo_id')
    ->whereNotNull('conciliaciones.vehiculo_id')
    ->get();
```

How can I make the query?

In the query, select other columns but is Similarly that I need in Laravel

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution xD

```
$conciliacion = DB::table('conciliaciones')
    ->leftJoin('vehiculos','vehiculos.id', '=', 'conciliaciones.vehiculo_id')
    ->select('conciliaciones.*','vehiculos.placa')
    ->orderBy('conciliaciones.id')        
    ->get();
```